# Apache POI XSSFWorkbook ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, servlets, apache-poi

I try to write a `Servlet` which have to write on local disc the `xlsx` file received from the client (this part works) and to read this `xlsx` file with Apache POI (here is the problem).

I mention that I tried to send and read a simple `txt` file and it works so, from the client it's not any problem. The problem is from the server when invoking `XSSFWorkbook` constructor.

I downloaded the `Apache POI 3.17 zip` package and I included all jar's in my project. I tried with a simple Java Project to test my code and it works, but when I need to made a Dynamic Web Project (Java EE) from Eclipse I received that error:

```
Sep 28, 2017 11:47:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [app.java.request.ExcelDownload] in context with path [/solutions] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at app.java.request.ExcelDownload.doPost(ExcelDownload.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The `servlet`:

```
package app.java.request;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

@WebServlet("/data/download")
public class ExcelDownload extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ExcelDownload() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
//      System.out.println("GET");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);

        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem item = iter.next();
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        File file = new File("D:\\EclipseOxygenWks\\files\\" + item.getName());
                        item.write(file);

                        FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream(file);
                        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);
                        //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
                    }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why I received that error because I am trying to find an answer from yesterday?

Comment: can you check poi-ooxml.jar is there or not in build path ? if not please add and check

Comment: Yes, is included in the build path (the code it works on a simple Java Project, but when I made a Dynamic Web Project with servlet it doesn't work).

Comment: It might be a possibility that "poi-ooxml.jar" is not present at the run-time. Please check on it.

Comment: How may I check?

Comment: you can check on java build path or  inside WEB-INF/lib

Comment: You can check it using your ".war" file, if that jar is included in your ".war" file or not. Are you using any build tool for this ?

Comment: It is attached... I attached all jar's from Apache POI 3.17 zip package to be sure that I don't miss a jar...

Comment: @Punit I am using only Eclipse.

Comment: try to add all the jars again build the path create a war & redeploy and check

Comment: Now it works, thank for your help. I downloaded the 3.15 version and I added again.

Comment: Same problem here. Is this a problem with POI version am also using 3.17. Shall I downgrade it to 3.15? Please advice struggling for two days. Thanks in advance.